# SelectSingleNode get attribute value

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to use the select single node to return a value from an XML that matches a particular xpath query.

This is the code I am using,

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Program Files\Config.xml");

string xPath;


xPath = "/Configuration/Service[@name='InfoRepositoryClient']/Environment/Parameter[@name='ORBPreferredInterfaces']";

string value = doc.SelectSingleNode(xPath).Attributes["value"].Value;

Console.WriteLine("The value is {0}", value);

Console.WriteLine("XML Doc is ...");
```

XML Sample,

```
<Configuration version="7.2.0" xmlns="event_collection/WinCollect">
<Service version="7.2.0.799013" classification="Service" type="Service" module="WinCollectCommon" name="RegistryCache">
    <Environment/>
</Service>
<Service version="7.2.0.799013" classification="Static" type="Service" module="AgentCore" name="AgentCore">
    <Environment>
        <Parameter value="300000" name="HeartbeatInterval"/>
        <Parameter value="60000" name="ConfigurationCheckInterval"/>
        <Parameter value="true" name="Enabled"/>
        <Parameter value="false" name="Deleted"/>
    </Environment>
</Service>
<Service version="7.2.0.799013" classification="Service" type="Service" module="WinCollectCommon" name="InfoRepositoryClient">
    <Environment>
        <Parameter value="0" name="DCPSDebugLevel"/>
        <Parameter value="*=127.0.0*" name="ORBPreferredInterfaces"/>
        <Parameter value="44380" name="DomainId"/>
        <Parameter value="corbaloc::127.0.0.1:12345/DCPSInfoRepo" name="DCPSInfoRepo"/>
        <Parameter value="1" name="DCPSBit"/>
    </Environment>
</Service>
```

When I run this I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. When I debug I see that my value is getting set to null.

I just want a quick query to pull out a value from an XML using XPath

Note when I run xpath query in notepad ++ I get the following results

> `1 hit`
>
> `Parameter`
>
> `- @Value: *=127.0.0*`
>
> `- @name: ORBPreferredInterfaces`

Answer (score 1):

Your xml file has default namespace `xmlns="event_collection/WinCollect"`, thus you cannot use only local names of nodes to get them. I'd go with Linq to Xml

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Program Files\Config.xml");
var ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

var parameter = 
    xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "Service")
        .Where(s => (string)s.Attribute("name") == "InfoRepositoryClient")
        .Elements(ns + "Environment")
        .Elements(ns + "Parameter")
        .Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("name") == "ORBPreferredInterfaces")
        .Select(p => (string)p.Attribute("value"))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Output:

```
"*=127.0.0*"
```

With XPath:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "event_collection/WinCollect");
var xpath = "ns:Service[@name='InfoRepositoryClient']/ns:Environment/ns:Parameter[@name='ORBPreferredInterfaces']";
var parameter = xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElement(xpath, nsmgr);
var value = (string)parameter.Attribute("value");
```

With old XmlDocument API:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Program Files\Config.xml");
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "event_collection/WinCollect");
var xpath = "ns:Service[@name='InfoRepositoryClient']/ns:Environment/ns:Parameter[@name='ORBPreferredInterfaces']";
var parameter = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xpath, nsmgr); 
string value = parameter.Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a default `xmlns` in play, viz `xmlns="event_collection/WinCollect"`, as inherited from the root `Configuration`. You should use an `XmlNameSpaceManager` to register the namespace, and then pass it to your `SelectSingleNode` calls:

```
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("e", "event_collection/WinCollect");
string value = doc.SelectSingleNode(xPath, nsm).Attributes["value"].Value;
```

You'll also need to qualify your xpath:

```
/e:Configuration/e:Service[@name='InfoRepositoryClient']
/e:Environment/e:Parameter[@name='ORBPreferredInterfaces']
```